# GWT i8n Plurals (using 2 plural forms in one paragraph not working -> bug in GWT compiler?)

Tags: java, gwt

I have the following Message definition in my Message class:

```
@DefaultMessage("{0,number} preceding items, and {1,number} " +
"followup items.")
@Description("Label showing the number of preceding items and " +
"follow-up items")
@AlternateMessage({
"none|one", "One follow-up item.",
"one|none", "One preceding item.",
"one|one", "One preceding item, and one follow-up item.",
"none|other", "{1,number} follow-up items.",
"other|none", "{0,number} preceding items.",
"one|other", "One preceding item, and {1,number} follow-up" +
" items.",
"other|one", "{0,number} preceding items, and one follow-up " +
"item."
})
String precedingAndFollowupItemCount(
@PluralCount(PluralRuleNoneOne.class) int precedingItemsCount,
@PluralCount(PluralRuleNoneOne.class) int followUpItemssCount);
```

I defined the PluralRuleNonOne.class as follows

```
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.impl.plurals.DefaultRule;
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.impl.plurals.DefaultRule_0_1_n;

public final class PluralRuleNoneOne extends DefaultRule {
@Override
public PluralForm[] pluralForms() {
    return DefaultRule_0_1_n.pluralForms();
}

@Override
public int select(final int n) {
    return DefaultRule_0_1_n.select(n);
}
```

Now the gwt compiler (with -extra) produces (among other things) the following properties file:

```
# Description: Label showing the number of preceding items and follow-up     
items
# 0=precedingItemssCount (Plural Count), 1=followUpItemsCount (Plural Count)
# - Default plural form
BE52173166487BB95708A7E45EB0752B={0,number} preceding items, and {1,number}    
follow-up items.
*# - plural form 'none': Count is 0
BE52173166487BB95708A7E45EB0752B[none]=
# - plural form 'one': Count is 1
BE52173166487BB95708A7E45EB0752B[one]=*
```

Now I wonder for what the highlighted properties stand for. As there are TWO parameters it seems impossible to have a property like BE52173166487BB95708A7E45EB0752B[none]=?

Furthermore, where did the alternate messages go like for example:

BE52173166487BB95708A7E45EB0752B[none|one]=One follow-up item.

Is this a bug in the GWT compiler or do I have some misconception in my Message class?

Thanks for any advice.

Hannes

Answer (score 4):

Just found the following posting: https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/7032 which resolves the issue:

You need to use @Generate(format = "com.google.gwt.i18n.server.PropertyCatalogFactory") in your Message classes.